# Android Eclipse Popup Message with Button

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button, popup

I would like to make it so, by a click of a button, there is a popup message.

Right now the popup comes as soon as I open the app.

BTW the button I want to trigger the popup is the about button in main.xml

Here is my main.xml (with the layout stuff):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#3DE400"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- background originally #d78a00 -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Sample App"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="60sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/creator"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/about"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:onClick="show" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.pranavsanghvi.sampleappv4;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alert.setTitle("About");
        alert.setMessage("Sample About");
        alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
            }
        });
        alert.show();


    }   
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show popup on about button click add the following in `onCreate()`

```
Button aboutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.about);
aboutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                alert.show();
            }
        });
```

just remove `alert.show();` from onCreate();

**update :-**

Are you getting **alert can't be resolved**? If so then either make alert global i.e. declare it outside `onCreate()`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// code
alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
// code
```

or make it final so that it is

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

also remove `alert.show();` which is in `onCreate();`

Comment: when i do that, i have two cannot be resolved's on the alert and on the addNewContact.. how can i fix that?

Comment: use `alert.show()` only inside `aboutbutton`'s `setOnClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

First, declare your alert and button in MainActivity:

```
public class Mainactivity extends Activity {
    private AlertDialog.Builder alert;
    private Button btAbout;

    //rest of the code
}
```

Then, in onCreate(), create your alert as you did, except this line:

```
alert.show();    // <--- remove this line as not to show the alert immediately
```

Because you've declared global alert, remember to also remove AlertDialog.Builder here, so instead of:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
alert.setTitle("About");

//rest of the code
```

you should have:

```
alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
alert.setTitle("About");

//rest of the code
```

Next, get the handle to your about button:

```
btAbout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.about);
```

Set onClickListener to button:

```
btAbout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //when this button is clicked, show the alert
        alert.show();
    }
});
```

All of this is in onCreate(). Now when button is clicked, your alert will be displayed.

Comment: everything works great except in "alert.show();" in "btAbout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {" the alert has an error that says "Cannot refer to a non-final variable alert inside an inner class defined by another method"

Comment: any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Have you declared `alert` in MainActivity, not in onCreate()?

Comment: yeah, exactly as you said. but i think the problem is because the alert is being used inside the onclicklistener while it is defined outside in the mainactivity

Comment: You need to remove AlertDialog.Builder in front of alert variable in onCreate(), otherwise, global alert is shadowed by the one in onCreate(). See my updated post.